# What do you think is the best way to keep a partitioning table unique?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

For example, when partitioning

```
    ===case list
alter table tbl_example partition by list columns(platform) (
      PARTITION p1 VALUES IN ('platform1'),
      PARTITION p2 VALUES IN ('platform2'),
      PARTITION p3 VALUES IN ('platform3'),
      PARTITION p4 VALUES IN ('platform4')
);
=== case day
alter table tbl_example partition by range(TO_DAYS(createdAt)) (
      partition r0 values less than (TO_DAYS('2022-08-01')), 
      partition r1 values less than (maxvalue)
);
```

When partitioning a list or range with this simple example
The table's id loses its uniqueness. where id is a value generated by short_id, not auto_increment.

There are two ways to avoid duplication here.

Although the table will increase, it is thought to be minute, so an additional column that follows the existing short_id, i.e., that follows the unique ID before partitioning, is inserted into both the ID and the additional column, and unique ID is applied to the additional column to prevent duplicate unique IDs. This is possible because the unique ID is the same as the additional column.

The second method is to check once if there is the same value as the unique ID before inserting data like before insert. However, in this case, since a check is required every time, there is a slight concern about latency in the service environment where a lot of inserts occur.

Comment: *where id is a value generated by short_id, not auto_increment* Unclear. Does programmatical `id` value generation is used? and maybe this is the source of the problem? and you're not treating the disease, but its symptom?

Comment: The short id is generated before insertion in the backend. Previously, the id value should not be duplicated because it was used for deletion, update, or join key.

Comment: If you use client-generated `id` value then the client must check for possible duplication. For example, use an attempt to reserve generated value and use it if it was reserved successful or generate another value if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We *must* see the queries to answer this kind of question.

If you don't have a million rows, don't bother with `PARTITIONing`.

Only `BY RANGE` provides any performance, and only in certain situations.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Too many ranges or too few ranges will hurt performance.  (I like 10 to 50, but that is not hard and fast.)

`AUTO_INCREMENT` requires *only* that it be the *first* column in *some* index.  As long as you don't deliberately try to set such a column, it won't matter that it is not declared unique.

What Uniqueness constraints do you really need?

You *may* have a "natural" PK, thereby avoiding `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Be aware that you should re-think *all* indexes when switching to/from Partitioning.  A simple, but partial, rule is that the "partition key" should be last, not first, in any indexes.

The cost of testing for Uniqueness is probably much worse than not having Partitioning.  It is likely to require an *extra* `SELECT`, and that may have to hit *every* partition.

A partitioned table is essentially a bunch of tables, plus "pruning" to pick which one (or several) tables to look in.

Comment: In other words, when partitioning, does it mean that pk is stable only if it is a non-overlapping unique key provided by mysql like auto_increment? If I set the pk value to bigint, can I go over the 2.1 billion range with auto_increment? Currently, the number of columns is 100 million, but there is room to go beyond that in the future.

Comment: @jeqwdkc - The "uniqueness" constraint is enforced only within one partition.  The 'normal' usage of Auto_increment will not generate any dups, but with partitioning one _could_ cheat and insert the same value in multiple partitions.  `INT UNSIGNED` gets to 4 billion (and still in 4 bytes); `BIGINT` goes much further.